# blur on no-hover items

Tags: javascript, css, blur

I need a bit help with blur efect :D
I have the follow:

```
<header>
            <div>Home</div>
            <div>Menu</div>
            <div>Settings</div>
            <div class="men">Account</div>
</header>
```

and the CSS:

```
header > div:hover{
    -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
    -moz-filter: blur(1px);
    -o-filter: blur(1px);
    -ms-filter: blur(1px);
    filter: blur(1px);

    color:#000;
    background-color:#FFF;
    height:120%;
}
```

If I'm hover a div it will use the blur effect, but... How can I do for add the blur effect on No-hover items?? I want all items with blur exept the hover. I guess that I will need javascript for this right?

Thanks all :D

Answer (score 3):

Using CSS only you can achieve this.

```
 header > div:hover{
color:#000;
background-color:#FFF;
height:120%;
}
header > div:hover ~ div{
-webkit-filter: blur(1px);
-moz-filter: blur(1px);
-o-filter: blur(1px);
-ms-filter: blur(1px);
filter: blur(1px);

color:#000;
background-color:#FFF;
height:120%;
}
```

**EDIT:**

The above will work only for next siblings element. Here is the complete solution for you scenario.

```
  header:hover > div{
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px);
  -o-filter: blur(1px);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);

    color:#000;
   background-color:#FFF;
    height:120%;
   }
  header > div:hover{
  color:#000;
  background-color:#FFF;
  height:120%;
 -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
 -moz-filter: blur(0px);
 -o-filter: blur(0px);
 -ms-filter: blur(0px);
 filter: blur(0px);

 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f6zdbdd1/)

Comment: It works, but only to divs that are on my right. For example, if I have 5 divs and I'm on the 3º, the 4º and 5º will take the blur efect, but the 1º and 2º no =/

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can't do this in CSS. If you're using javascript, you can archive this with the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event.

Comment: can you add some example? I'm so stuppid por javascript xDDD

Comment: Using jQuery it looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/655ahm5m/

The only thing you have to change is the css properties you want (including prefixes)